# How to save multiple seaborn plots to the same pdf/png file?

Tags: python, pdf, pandas, seaborn

I'm struggling to save the a few plots on the same pdf.
The data source is a dataframe.
I considered saving them as png, but that is not practical at all..

```
pdf_pages = PdfPages('kde.pdf')
for i in range(1,114):
    for j in range(0,113):
        x=t1.iloc[:,i]
        y=t1.iloc[:,j]
        fig=sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, kind="kde",dropna=True);
        pdf_pages.savefig(fig)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seaborn's `jointplot` does not return a `figure`, it returns a `seaborn.JointGrid` instance.

You need to pass a figure to `pdf_pages.savefig`, so use:

```
with PdfPages('kde.pdf') as pdf_pages:
    for i in range(1, 114):
        for j in range(0, 113):
            x=t1.iloc[:, i]
            y=t1.iloc[:, j]
            joint_grid = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, kind="kde", dropna=True)
            pdf_pages.savefig(joint_grid.fig)
```

Comment: just want to point out from my struggle in adapting this, if using ``snsplot = sns.heatmap()`` instead then  to save use ``pdf_pages.savefig(snsplot.figure)``

Comment: same point as muon mentioned happends regarding ````sns.distplot()````